# What venues should we tap for users?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, new-users

If we are to attract interested and interesting users from around the web, it seems advisable to get the name and link of judaism.SE to appear in strategic places. Examples might include blogs on topics related to ours or the facebook pages of groups with shared interests.

What are some specific places, people or sites that we should target for potential users and are within our purview of feasible harnessability?

Comment: This is a good question but ultimately listing places to link from is useless without a means of getting those places to link.

Comment: @msh210 Edited to reflect the narrower intent of sites we can expect to be able to use.

Answer (score 1):

I'm making this community wiki so people can add to it (and subtract from it if necessary). (I don't browse the Jewish Web as much as others here doubtless do, so I expect my own contribution to this answer to be dwarfed by others'.)

[AishDas](http://www.aishdas.org/)'s blogs, "Avodah" listserv, and, perhaps, other fora.

Likewise, fora on:

- http://torah.org/
- http://aish.com/
- http://ohr.edu/
- IF we have the money we may try http://www.theyehivaworld.com. If anyone has an account in their "coffeeroom" we could try there.

And these individual blogs:

- http://www.cross-currents.com/
- http://www.beyondbt.com/
- http://www.TorahMusings.com/

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason not to approach individual communities, and ask them to publicize.

I mean *real world* communities, not just online ones - e.g. batei knissiyot, synogagues, yeshivot, etc.

A lot of them have mailing lists nowadays, and some (though not all) would agree to provide their members with informative links to appropriate sites, such as this one.

The next step, would be to get the community and yeshiva rabbanim to join, and bring with them their students and kehilla.

Comment: An ad in _Jewish Action_? In some publication read by the YU community? In similar publications? Perhaps this should be a separate question.....