# LAUNCH IS COMING! How shall we promote it?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion, launch

Dear Fellow Yodeyans<sup>1</sup>,

I have exciting news for those of you who haven't been following chat for the past few days. It seems that **Judaism.SE is [slated](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=4250132#4250132) to launch out of beta within the next few weeks!** That means that we'll become a full-fledged member of the [Stack Exchange network](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid#) with, among other things, our own distinctive logo and site design.

This news comes from [Jin Yang](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/417/jin), Stack Exchange's resident designer, who's been working on the design for our site. He has already [shown us](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=4239416#4239416) a draft of what the site's logo could look like, and I, for one, am very impressed. Oh, and did you notice the name in that logo? Yes, that would be **"Mi Yodeya," which [will](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=4234909#4234909) once [again](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/where-did-all-these-posts-come-from) be the site's name**

So, given that launch is coming, we've got some work to do. This launch will be a major milestone for the site and will be a great opportunity to promote the "new" site to people who haven't been here yet, or haven't been here for a while.

- **What should we do to promote the newly-launched site?**
- **What will *you* do to promote the launch?**

Please post ideas as answers to this question and/or as separate meta posts.

Let's take this opportunity to make more people aware of this fantastic community and resource!

---

For reference, here are some previous [site-promotion](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-promotion) initiatives that could stand to be re-kindled for the launch:

- [Contact reporters to promote this site!](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320/contact-reporters-to-promote-this-site)
- [How can we encourage people to link to content here?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151/how-can-we-encourage-people-to-link-to-content-here)
- [What venues should we tap for users?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197/what-venues-should-we-tap-for-users)
- [Please post links to J.SE content on other sites!](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237/please-post-links-to-j-se-content-on-other-sites)

And [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/04/more-notes-on-contest-format/) are Stack Exchange's latest thoughts on contests.

---

<sup>1) I know this is a bit pre-mature (see below), but I'm OK with that.</sup>

Comment: As an interested party: congratulations, I wish you the best, and I hope you find some ways to further promote your site.  I'm not sure how effective it is, but Christianity has a [blog](http://christianity.blogoverflow.com/) for promoting itself.  If y'all started one, I'd be a regular reader.

Comment: @JonEricson, Thanks! Believe me, I would too.