# Shall we have a launch party?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion, launch

To promote our [impending launch](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1001/launch-is-coming-how-shall-we-promote-it), I think it would be cool to have a launch party. Some elements that it could include:

- Live text chat
- Live audio
- A call-in show format, using [BlogTalkRadio](http://www.blogtalkradio.com/).
- People identifying favorite site content to date.
- A ribbon-cutting in which we count down to a SE staff person throwing the switch to launch the new design, and we all reload and see the new site at once.
- Divrei Torah
- A panel discussion, featuring notable people from within and/or outside the site, on some relevant topic, such as "the role of online communities in discussion of Halachic topics."
- A synchronized "Lechaim," with each participant using their own beverage of choice, perhaps with some dignitary delivering words of blessing. (Inspired by food-oriented comments from Double AA, Shmuel Brin, Dave, and Gershon Gold.)

What do you think of this idea? What aspects would you like to see or not see? Any other ideas?

Comment: How would the live audio be implemented?

Comment: @HodofHod I'm not sure. Stack Exchange did a live feed for their [podcasts](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/), so maybe we could use whatever they did. Another possibility could be [BlogTalkRadio](http://www.blogtalkradio.com/).

Comment: Maybe we can serve some food and make it a _Lunch_ party.

Comment: @DoubleAA How would it work? A video of Isaac Moses eating a pizza? :)

Comment: @ShmuelBrin - More likely [pureed berries](http://lo.yodeya.com/2010/03/miyodeya-online-community-for-q-about.html). :)

Comment: @Dave I don't care if they're pureed, as long as they're berya-less berries. Speaking of which, anyone want to create a viral video to promote our launch? (... or somehow get that one to go viral? It's just as relevant now as it was then.)

Comment: Ever hear of a Jewish party without food? Got to figure in the food somehow.

Comment: @GershonGold, we could invite everyone to BYOB, and we could all drink a "Lechaim" together.

Comment: What is BYOB???????????

Comment: @GershonGold, Sorry; it means "bring your own bottle."

Comment: My bottle is finished already. Plus I am also looking for some Fleish.

Comment: [My comment](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/shall-we-have-a-launch-party#comment2339_1002) wasn't food related?

Comment: @DoubleAA I apologize for the oversight. Let Geula come now, hopefully with plenty of refreshments.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Amen!

Comment: FYI, we typically launch sites on Tue or Wed, around 3-4pm EST. For voice/video chat, you can try Google Plus hangout(requires an Gmail account). It hosts max of 10 concurrent users though.

Answer (score 6):

Launch will most likely be on the afternoon (EDT) of Tuesday, May 8. I propose that we have a launch party, but on a later date, for the following reasons:

- That date falls during the part of Sefirat Ha'omer which is slated for mourning according to all options. Though the party may not technically violate the Sefira mourning rules, it still may not be 100% appropriate at that time.
- Because the actual launch will be during business hours (US), we won't be timing the launch party to coincide with it anyway.
- If we delay a bit, we'll have more time to plan cool stuff.

Stay tuned for an announcement of an in-chat planning meeting.

Comment: If we push it off two days we won't have the sefirah issue.

Comment: @DoubleAA: I suspect people are going to be a little busy that day with other things. (I know I am - two upsherenishes, one of which is my son's, bez"h.)

Comment: @Alex, Mazal Tov! Which reminds me - with MY being reborn as a tree, will we need to wait three years before we can start benefiting from it?

Comment: @IsaacMoses: thanks! Fortunately, Rambam (Hil. Maaser Sheni 10:4) says that if you plant a tree in your property for the use of the public, and it's outside of Eretz Yisrael, then the rules of orlah don't apply. So here, since you own the domain, make it available to the community, and you live in St. Louis, then we're good on all three counts. :)

Comment: @Alex I own the domain, but SEI owns the site as well as the design, and (I hope) will eventually own the domain as well. SEI makes all of the above open to the public and is based in Manhattan, so your logic still applies.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1078/2) are a transcript and a summary of key decisions from a planning meeting the community held for this party.