# Planning Meeting on Monday night, May 7 for a Launch Party

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion, chat, launch

Please come to [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/jewish-life-and-learning) on Monday, May 7 at 10:00 pm EDT for a planning meeting for our [Launch Party](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/shall-we-have-a-launch-party). You can register for the chat and get a doodad for your calendar [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/468/jewish-life-and-learning?tab=schedule).

**Purpose:**

- Plan a party to celebrate our [launch](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1045/design-for-mi-yodeya) out of beta and possibly also act as a tool for promoting the site to new users.

**Agenda:**

- What elements will the party include?

  (Some ideas are [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/shall-we-have-a-launch-party).)
- Who will arrange each piece that needs arranging?
- On what date and time will the party be scheduled?
- How will we promote the party?

As we make decisions, an answer to this post will be edited to reflect them.

Sorry about the last-minute and US-centric scheduling; it's just the way this had to go this time. Hopefully, the party itself will be more deliberately planned.

Answer (score 3):

[Here's the meeting transcript.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/conversation/launch-party-planning-meeting)

Key decisions:

- The party will be, B"H, on Sunday, June 3, 2012, at 9pm IDT / 2pm EDT / 11am PDT. (Register [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/468/jewish-life-and-learning?tab=schedule).)
- We will spend the next week (through Monday, May 14) trying to assemble panelists for a panel discussion.

  - Isaac will re-contact R' Torczyner and Joel Spolsky and will possibly also contact R's Student and Waxman.
  - Alex will contact Sara Esther Crispe.
- One possible element will be a call-in game. Alex has game materials which he will provide to WAF, who can run the game.
- Alex and Dave will prepare ~2-minute divrei Torah. Alex will read his, and msh210 will read Dave's.
- Jin is willing to create an ad for the party, once we nail down the content.
- We'll discuss a promotion plan after we nail down the content and ask for the ad.

Comment: I've created http://tinyurl.com/yodeyachat & http://snurl.com/yodeya & http://snipurl.com/yodeya to redirect to the chat room, in case it is advantageous to announce the room's URL online. (I made more than one, as I wasn't sure which was best. Obviously, any further suggestion are welcome, or simply say "click 'chat', atop any page of the site".

Comment: @msh210, Thanks! We could also use [Selected_Name](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1111/final-vote-to-name-mi-yodeyas-chat-room).yodeya.com, chat.yodeya.com, chat.miyodeya.com, or any subdomain of one of those domains that we want.

Comment: ... and we can also make a similar link for the live audio.