# How shall we celebrate Mi Yodeya's fifth birthday?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

On 6 December 2009 (19 Kislev 5770) [question #1](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1) was asked, launching this excellent site.  The fifth anniversary of Mi Yodeya's arrival in the world will, B"H, be coming up on 6 December (secular calendar) or 11 December (19 Kislev).

How shall we celebrate this?

(Yes Isaac, I [noticed what you said there](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=14379181#14379181). :-) )

Comment: Straw poll: upvote this comment if you'd come to a [Mi Yodeya Shabbaton](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1626/5323) in, say, the New York area.

Comment: @Shokhet There are [data](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1635/where-do-you-live) that suggest that at least a plurality live in the New York area.

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1002/759

Comment: @DoubleAA, you want to do another radio show?

Comment: @Shokhet I upvoted your comment assuming Silver Spring, before seeing the edit to say New York.  I probably wouldn't go to NY. :-(

Comment: @IsaacMoses I'm not for or opposed, but it seemed like a relevant post to link to

Comment: @MonicaCellio :( ....I guess I'll just take your vote, then....

Comment: It might make more sense to celebrate the 22nd of Kislev as the birthday of this community, since that's the anniversary of the [first time](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13/2) one person posted a real question here, and another answered it.

Comment: Let's all listen to our favourite rendition of 'Hava Nagila'! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p7fB06S8Bq8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not to preclude any other ideas (and perhaps to complement them somehow), there will be an in-person celebration on Shabbat Parashat Vayeishev (Dec. 12-13) in Silver Spring, MD. By default, it will be one Shabbat meal for Yodeyans who happen to live in the area (and their families). If people are interested in coming in from out of town, we can put together a fuller-fledged [Shabbat program](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1626/how-can-we-plan-a-shabbaton-mi-yodeya).

Either way, I am proposing as a theme **Mikra / Scripture**, given that Mi Yodeya's turning five and the curriculum in [Avot 5:21](http://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.5.21).

If you are interested in attending, please send me an email at the email address indicated in my profile (or any other email address you happen to have for me).

Comment: If anybody is interested in carpooling from (or would be passing through) Pittsburgh, please drop me a note at (my last name) (at) pobox.com.

Comment: Gah we need one of these in the Midwest. Isaac, why did you have to move?

Comment: @Daniel to give you the opportunity to organize one.  Meanwhile, he's now within driving distance of me. :-)

Comment: The celebration was most excellent, with good company and much torah talk. Thank you very much for hosting, and thanks to all who came!

Answer (score 6):

How about making us some more [swag](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1374/mi-yodeya-top-user-swag)?

(Yes, i noticed this in Bam.)

Comment: There's nothing technically preventing us from throwing the MY logo onto, e.g. http://CafePress.com merchandise. I don't know if that would be cool with the owners of the logo (SE, Inc.).

Comment: @IsaacMoses [We'd rather you didn't.](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance)

Answer (score 2):

The last time Mi Yodeya had [a planning post for a celebration](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1002/759) was for our [Launch Party](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1134/mi-yodeya-launch-party), which was a live online radio call-in show. We could maybe do another one of those.

If you like this idea, please edit this post and/or comment on it to help flesh it out, and consider volunteering to help make it happen.

A couple of possibilities for show format include trial runs of either a [Parsha "gabfest"](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1386/parashat-hashavua-gabfest) or a [Real-time Parsha Q&A Call-in Show](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/282/idea-weekly-podcast/2245#2245).

Answer (score 2):

I propose that at Shabbat lunch on Shabbat Parashat Vayeishev (Dec. 12-13), people inclined to celebrate Mi Yodeya should:

- Say a devar Torah. (If you need an idea for one, you could always read a [Q&A about the parsha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashat-vayeishev).)
- Raise a glass to Mi Yodeya and bless each other and our community with "*Lechayim!*"

That way, we can all celebrate together in spirit, if not in person.

If you plan to do this or have done this, please leave a comment on this post, so that everyone else can have an idea of whom they celebrated with.

Comment: A bunch of Yodeyans [will be](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2242/2) eating, drinking, and sharing Torah together in Silver Spring, MD.